# Can't i get Kubernetes version in my local machine

Tags: kubernetes

i'm about to jump a bit to Kubernetes to see how it work and perform, i had a small problem that block me:

```
kubectl version
```

`Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.3", GitCommit:"029c3a408176b55c30846f0faedf56aae5992e9b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-02-17T20:48:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

*i'm running tests on Mac El Capitane

Any help ?

Comment: Hi, how did you create your cluster? In case you use minikube, you might have to run `kubectl config use-context minikube` upfront

Comment: @pagid No, still fresh installation, can't even get the version :/

Comment: How did you create the Cluster?

Comment: Not yet, i've tried but i still get the same message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response indicates you did not create a Kubernetes Server.

Note that `kubectl` is the client tool which talks to a Kubernetes server.

You may want to use [Kubernetes/minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) to run Kubernetes locally.

Or follow [Kubernetes workshop](https://github.com/cloud-native-singapore/kubernetes-workshop) to leverage a GKE hosted cluster.